# Make iOS devices by default connect to external audio sources (Airplay/Bluetooth)?

Tags: macos, ios, audio, bluetooth, airplay

Is there a way to get an iOS device to connect to an Airplay server and/or Bluetooth audio device *by default*?

I would like my iPad to use my Mac computer's speakers by default, instead of the iPad internal speakers.

I can think of two options:

- Run an AirServer or Airfoil server on the Mac, and somehow get the iPad to connect to that Airplay server by default when it's online.
- Trick the iPad into believing that the Mac is a Bluetooth speaker, and get it to connect there by default.

Both options above would probably require some sort of third-party software like [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/) or [Airfoil](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) – or something for Bluetooth – but the big question is if it's possible to get an iOS device to connect by default to an external sound source.

---

*Btw*, the way I solve this problem today is simply connecting the iPad to my speakers via an Aux 3.5 mm cable, and simply bypass the computer altogether. I am however thinking of getting a portable Bluetooth speaker or a portable Airplay speaker, and I'm trying to learn how easy it is to use these technologies to use a default audio output. A big advantage of Bluetooth over Airplay would be if it's easier to set a standard output device via Bluetooth, rather than having to use the pesky iOS control center every time one of the devices are put to sleep or shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you can only set the default audio routing for calls (phone calls, Skype, FaceTime) by changing the setting for it in Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Call Audio Routing.

There is no method to change the default audio routing for media at this point in time.